# I do not get the use of " what time" in Dickens A Tale of Two Cities

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> **What time**, the mail-coach lumbered, jolted, rattled, and bumped upon its tedious way, with its three fellow-inscrutables inside. To whom, likewise, the shadows of the night revealed themselves, in the forms their dozing eyes and wandering thoughts suggested.

The preceding passage is from Dickens' A Tale of Two Cities Chapter 3, I do not get the use of " what" before Time. Please explain.

Comment: Chatgtp may or may not know what it's talking about, but it says *In this context, the phrase "What time" is an archaic way of saying "while" or "at the same time as."* If that's correct, (I don't know, myself! :) then the modern equivalent in context would be ***Meanwhile...***

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that it means "*For how long*", it's invented by Dickens, and he is purposefully not using normal English sentence structure, so there's little for a language learner to learn.

But in case you want want more detail...

Both "sentences" in that paragraph are just fragments, not sentences at all.

He does this to evoke a scene without naming a subject or having a main verb. It's just a scene of a mail coach moving on a bumpy road, and he's inviting the reader to imagine how long it took.

The sentence fragment that follows the one you're asking about is also a question-fragment-sentence mix. It includes the word "likewise", to signal the reader he's using the same non-standard structure again.

The second fragment is even more poetic and harder to parse. It's difficult to find a straightforward meaning, but it paints a picture, and invites the reader to imagine the people watching the mail coach pass by.

He returns to normal sentences in the paragraph after.

Comment: Eh? The second sentence is certainly a sentence ("The shadows of the night revealied themselves"), with an anaphoric "to whom" as the object. I think the first is a sentence as well, and that "What time" means "Meanwhile".

Comment: I parsed it as, "to whom the shadows of the night revealed themselves", which is not a sentence. But your reading may be correct. The same structure could apply to the first as well: "*The mail-coach lumbered ... on its way **what time** with ... inside*". I'm not sure how it's anaphoric though, as "to whom" precedes the rest of the sentence and there's no referent in it.

Comment: _To whom_ is certainly anaphoric: the referent is the three fellow-inscrutables. _What time_ may also be, depending on whether there is a time reference in the preceding sentence.